# Custom data not saving to members on checkout

Tags: cartthrob, members

I'm trying to save some custom member fields to EE's member section using CartThrob's checkout form.

I have created all the necessary member fields and mapped some of the basic fields in CartThrob's settings and they save just fine. Only the custom_data inputs don't save in the newly created EE member.

Here's the gist of what my form looks like so far:

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form create_user="yes" group_id="5"}    
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" id="first_name" class="required"  />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" id="last_name" class="required"  />
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Preferred Name" name="custom_data[preferred_name]" />
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="DOB Day" name="custom_data[member_dob_day]" />
{/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}
```

This was all done following [CartThrob's docs](http://cartthrob.com/docs/backend/members/index.html#member-data) and many iterations of not working.
Any direction guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this post useful which shows how we approached this scenario.

[Cartthrob checkout form with different billing and member information](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21339/cartthrob-checkout-form-with-different-billing-and-member-information/21343#21343)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the id is missing in your custom_data inputs.

Try it like this:

```
<input name="custom_data[whatever]" id="custom_data[whatever]" />
```